# Plugin connection error when using Exynap

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Exynap connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjKn7.png)

This plugin seems to be broken for me. Ive tried re installing it, updating the android studio version, and running android studio as admin. Ive also tried using the 'no proxy' option in the Http proxy settings as well as trying the 'auto-detect proxy settings'.

Ive noticed i would get the following error in the bottom within a yellow dialog when i try to use Exynap and it states 'suggestions are not available right now'.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.